# Need help in creating API level Shopify Webhooks - Its driving me crazy

Tags: shopify, webhooks

I am new to Shopify, and working on a shop right now. I am developing an app (shopify_app example using RoR) where I need to use the API level Webhooks.

I have read the Shopify Webhook documents, But I am completely dont understand it.

can some one write/help me on how to create for one 'orders/create' topic

few question that I have

In which controller I have to create the webhooks, How can I confirm that Webhook is created, how can i delete it

I have tried few examples and ended up with frustation. I just need complete example for topic 'orders/create' so that I can explore.

I have tried the following code, But I completely dont understand what is happening

webhook = ShopifyAPI::Webhook.new(:format => "json", :topic => "products/update", :address => "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/webhooks/api.php")

raise "Webhook invalid: #{webhook.errors}" unless webhook.valid?

puts webhook # printing # which I dont understand what is happening

Please some one help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try using the Ruby based Shopify console:

http://docs.shopify.com/api/introduction/using-the-api-console

Once you're comfortable with the API mechanics of registering a webhook, then start coding again.

Next, I would use a tool like Requestb.in (http://requestb.in) or Runscope Request Capture (https://www.runscope.com/docs/request-capture) as my testing hook URLs, because you'll be confident that those services will capture any incoming data, eliminating any doubt that the hook was properly registered and/or an event fired.